# C++: Access to a public member function from outside of a class

Tags: c++, class, member-functions

I have a class defined in a separate file and at some point I need to access one of the public member functions from another source file. For some reason, I forgot how to do that and compiler gives me an error.

I have classA.h with definition of class A similar to this:

```
class classA {
  public:
  int function1(int alpha);
}
```

And a separate file classA.cpp with the implementation. And then in some other file blah.cpp I include the header and try to access it like this:

```
 classA::function1(15);
```

and my compiler refuses it with error that it could not find a match for 'classA::function1(int)'.
I use Embarcadero RAD studio 2010 if that matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To call a 'normal' function, you need an instance.

```
classA a;
a.function1(15);
```

If you want to call the function using `classA::` then it needs to be `static`.

```
classA {
  public:
    static int function1(int alpha);
};

//...
classA::function1(15);
```

Note that inside a static method, you can't access any non-static member variables, for the same reason - there is no instance to provide context.

Comment: or `classA` needs to be a namespace.

Comment: @Naveen: true, but that would be a *really* bad name for a namespace :)

Answer (score 1):

Is function1 a static method ? If no, then you need an object of that class to call a member function.

Include classA.h in your blah.cpp and create an object of Class A and then call the member function.